# My onchange is not working

Tags: javascript, jsp-tags

I need to double the price but the function is not working. The total not display. Below is the code.

This is my form:

```
<label>Price</label>
<input type="text" id="price" name="price" value="<%=rs.getDouble(2)%>" onchange="autoprice()"/>

<label>Total</label>
<input type="text" id="total" name="total" readonly="readonly"/>
```

my script:

```
<script>           
   function autoprice(){                 
      var x = document.getElementById("price").value;
      document.getElementById("total").value = (x * 2).toFixed(2);
   }
</script>
```

Comment: what is the error>

Comment: it is working on my end! what is the issue you are facing. Remember that the onchange is triggered when you focus out of the input box.

Comment: I guess you need to use `oninput` instead of `onchange`

Comment: oninput still not working

Answer (score 0):

Here I made a snippet of your code and its working fine.

```js
function autoprice() {
  var x = document.getElementById("price").value;
  document.getElementById("total").value = (x * 2).toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<label>Price</label>
<input type="text" id="price" name="price" value="" onchange="autoprice()" />

<label>Total</label>
<input type="text" id="total" name="total" readonly="readonly" />
```

Comment: No it will not affect the function. Are you getting value from database?

Comment: Yes. I'm getting value from database. I finally resolved it. I should not use onchange/oninput as I want the value to display but instead I use onpageshow. Thank you everyone for helping . I'm still new in this field.

Answer (score 0):

Onchange needs the cursor move out of focus. After entering value press Tab or Enter. Use oninput, if you want to change it dynamically when the value is changed like the below code.

```
<label>Price</label>
<input type="text" id="price" name="price" value="" oninput="autoprice()"/>

<label>Total</label>
<input type="text" id="total" name="total" readonly="readonly"/>

<script>           
   function autoprice(){                 
      var x = document.getElementById("price").value;
      document.getElementById("total").value = (x * 2).toFixed(2);
   }
</script>
```